# Using display:inline-block and vertically alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I am using `display:inline` instead of `float:left` to create 4 blocks that horizontally align in the center when there isn't enough room. I was able to remove the unwanted horizontal margins by removing the whitespace between inline elements, but now it seems I have unwanted vertically margins.

Although it's not really margin so much as it's the baseline of the elements(because they are treated like text) that is off. In my jsFiddle example, you can see the problem. I have more text in the second block, but it is aligned up vertically on the baseline, creating what appears to be a margin at the top.

What can I do to make sure they line up correctly vertically without adding a bunch of wrappers? Removing the appearance of unwanted vertical margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper-pricebox">
<div class="pricebox">
<span>Yikes</span>
<h5>Block One</h5>
blah blah blah...
</div><div class="pricebox">
<span>Yikes</span>
<h5>Block Two</h5>
blah blah blah...blah blah blah...
</div><div class="pricebox">
<span>Yikes</span>
<h5>Block Three</h5>
blah blah blah...
</div><div class="pricebox">
<span>Yikes</span>
<h5>Block Four</h5>
blah blah blah...
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper-pricebox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.pricebox {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 7px;
    width: 23%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: 2px solid #444 !important;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jd866/

Comment: I aggre with @andrew, vertical-align:top should do the trick.

Comment: @Örvar it does the trick, but is it semantic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5VCch/

I added `vertical-align:top`

Comment: +1 I've been trying to search for an alternative to vertical-align, but it seems like that is the only way to give inline-block elements floating behavior.

Comment: I thought of using `vertical-align`, but I thought it was non-semantic to use it without `display:table-cell`, which in turn has to have a parent with `display:table`?